# Android app is not Running

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

Hello Everyone I have a problem.
I'm trying to build an app i join a button which is in the main activity and try to connect another activity which opens just by clicking on this button. I used intent here is the java code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button exitbu;
    Button aboutbu;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    aboutbu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutbu);
    aboutbu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent("com.nomzapp.ABOUT");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    exitbu= (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitbu);
    exitbu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

}
```

But When i run this app in emulator or in mobile. The app stops after the splash screen. ( force close message box appear )
Here is the Manifesto

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nomzapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.nomzapp.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.nomzapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.nomzapp.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.nomzapp.About"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.nomzapp.ABOUT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>

</application>
```

Any help ??
I want my app to run and main page appears and when i click about button the about activity must start
Here is LogCat

```
01-12 02:27:49.972: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 53% free   2552K/5379K,   external 1625K/2137K, paused 243ms
01-12 02:27:51.088: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 53% free 2551K/5379K, external 2580K/3222K, paused 229ms
01-12 02:27:56.507: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 53% free 2569K/5379K, external 2699K/3654K, paused 70ms
01-12 02:27:56.737: D/dalvikvm(540): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 2569K/5379K, external 3824K/4776K, paused 61ms
01-12 02:27:56.948: D/AndroidRuntime(540): Shutting down VM
01-12 02:27:56.948: W/dalvikvm(540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nomzapp/com.nomzapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:507)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.nomzapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-12 02:27:56.958: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  ... 11 more
01-12 02:27:59.248: I/Process(540): Sending signal. PID: 540 SIG: 9
```

And on more thing before adding about button and class.The app was running well.

Comment: I posted the solution for the buttons to run proper. Can you attach to your questions the logcat of the crash?

Comment: You are not supposed to  use `System.exit(0);`. Instead, try something like `finish()`

Comment: iGio90  I attach the logcat

Comment: gian1200  It is running well.

Comment: Please post your layout xml file.

Comment: please post your complete layouts and .java files as it seems that you are making an android project for first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.nomzapp.About;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button exitbu;
    Button aboutbu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    aboutbu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutbu);
    aboutbu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    exitbu= (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitbu);
    exitbu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

}
```

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nomzapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.nomzapp.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.nomzapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
     <activity android:name="com.nomzapp.About"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

</application>
```

Comment: comment here the line 19 of your main activity! i'll update my reply and post you the final solution!

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
    startActivity(i);
   }

Comment: Anything else you need. Your help is much required because i m stuck on it since 4 days.

Comment: attach the layout with the buttons and the about class!

Comment: The code in onClick is only performed when you click the button, but the app already crashes when the activity is started.

Comment: What was the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event handler should look like this

@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

```
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ABOUT.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

}

Comment: in that case check ur layout.xml fiel for the MainActivity and make sure ur button id is defined , and that the spelling / letter case are the same as defined in ur findViewById

Answer (score 0):

It seems the layout you are loading does not contain the button with the ID R.id.aboutbu or  R.id.exitbu.

Could you check whether your buttons are not null when you assign the ClickListeners to them?

Just place breakpoints after you assign the buttons or add

```
Log.d(--YOURTAG--, --BUTTONNAME-- == null ? "Button null":"Button not null");
```

After you assign the button.